# How can I join a variable from a different dataset with two if_else statements?

Tags: r, database, dataframe, data-wrangling

let's say I have df1:

| Country | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Country A | 2010-08-10 |
| Country B | 2010-10-10 |
| Country C | 2010-11-10 |
| Country A | 2011-09-10 |
| Country A | 2015-08-10 |

and I have df2

| Ranking | Country | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Country A | 2010-07-10 |
| 8 | Country B | 2010-07-10 |
| 27 | Country C | 2010-07-10 |
| 6 | Country A | 2010-09-10 |
| 10 | Country B | 2010-09-10 |
| 20 | Country C | 2010-09-10 |
| 16 | Country A | 2010-10-10 |
| 3 | Country B | 2010-10-10 |
| 27 | Country C | 2010-10-10 |
| 10 | Country A | 2011-08-10 |
| 1 | Country A | 2015-07-10 |

How can I make a table that would like this?

| Country | Date | Ranking |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Country A | 2010-08-10 | 5 |
| Country B | 2010-10-10 | 8 |
| Country C | 2010-11-10 | 27 |
| Country A | 2011-09-10 | 10 |
| Country A | 2015-08-10 | 1 |

So that the country has the ranking from a month before.
I tried but I cannot figure it out. This is what I have

```
df1 <- df1 %>% 
mutate(ranking = if_else(Date > df2$Ranking & Country == df2$Country, df2$Country, df2$Country))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could do this by joining the tables, where one table's Date is offset by a month.

```
library(dplyr); library(lubridate)
df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2 %>% mutate(Date = Date %m+% months(1)))
```

One bit of warning "from a month before" is ambiguous and sometimes tricky. What day is a month before March 30?

---

Edit: if we want "prior rank in the data", then:

```
df1 %>%
  left_join(df2 %>% 
    group_by(Country) %>%
    arrange(Date) %>%
    mutate(Rank = lead(Rank),
           Date = lead(Date))
```

This would take all the df2 Rank + Date values and use the next one in the data.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer and sorry for the ambiguity! I meant from the rank before. So, not necessarily a month, but from the last rank